# Inner Class is not defined, though it is defined - Python

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I encountered an issue in which I created a class Student in which each student uses Laptops. So I made an inner Class laptop.

And then it shows an error ->

`NameError: name 'Laptop' is not defined`

FYI: Below code is given, if any issue, pls correct.

```
class Student:


    def __init__(self,name,rollno):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = Laptop()

    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.rollno)

    class Laptop:
        def __init__(self):
            self.brand = 'HP'
            self.cpu = 'i7'
            self.ram = 65



student1 = Student('Lohit',99)
student2 = Student('Brad',95)

print("Lohit's laptop's configuration -> \n Brand: {} \n CPU: {} \n RAM: {}GB".format(student1.lap.brand,student1.lap.cpu,student1.lap.ram))
```

After that, in the initialization of student1, the issue came.

Pls help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Why do you define the class inside a class?
Either define it outdoes of the 'Student' class and use it like you did, or use the 'self' word to access the 'Laptop' class as it's defined inside your 'Student' class.

Comment: instead of creating LAptop class you can do this way __self.lap = type("Laptop",(), {"brand": "HP", "cpu": 17, "ram": 65})__

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
self.lap = Laptop()
```

to

```
self.lap = self.Laptop()
```

Comment: better:  `Student.Laptop()`.